# jquery ui dialog custom button design

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I want to change default buttons with another ones. I have a modal dialog with two buttons: YES, NO.

I need that both buttons have 57px height and 80px width.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ThemeRoller or you can make another CSS and include it after the jQueryUI's css. For the second option, you can do this:

```
.ui-button{
    width: 80px;
    height: 57px;
}
```

Good luck :D